# In some moments vim works noticeably slowly

Tags: vim

In some moments vim works noticeably slow. When I'm in normal mode in 100 line file, type "**O**" *(uppercase letter o)* it **appears about 1-2 seconds** and only then above of current line new empty line is created in insert mode *(that is normal behavior)*. And I want to know possible reasons why this happens...

I have quite powerful computer, So the problem is not in computer.

Comment: To the one who voted this question 'off topic': what forum would it be more on-topic and why is it not related to programming? - There are people who make a living with programming, and vim is their tool to achieve what they are supposed to achieve, and if vim is slow it is certainly related to programming.

Comment: are there any notable messages (``:messages`)? If your vim is built with profiling support, you could try `:prof start` to see which operation takes most time... Usually, this feature is not compiled in, but you can build vim very easy by yourself...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you hitting `<Esc>` then `O` in very rapid succession? If so, you are seeing the delay due to certain terminal escape sequences beginning with `<Esc>O`. Vim has to wait to see if you are actually typing one of those sequences.

To see this for yourself, in insert mode type `<Esc>OA` and your cursor should move up.  Pressing `<Ctrl-v><Up>` in insert mode will show you the escape code generated.

Comment: Yes, I'm typing too fast. I experimented that situation and you are absolutely right. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

Type `:map O`

If you have a normal mapping starting with a capital `O`, it might be possible that Vim is waiting for a timeout to be sure that you are not starting to type a complex command.

Typically, the timeout default is of 1 second.

See `:help timeout` and `:help timeoutlen`.

If you do have a mapping starting with `O`, you can find where it is defined with `:verbose map`. You can then disable it or modify it (or remove the plugin defining the mapping).

Comment: @skeept : good remark, I didn't know it was possible. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting response, but "No mapping found". Not always appears O but sometimes... If I had mapping it would be always.

Answer (score 1):

May be you have a redefined key binding that starts with "O"... so VIM must wait to see if you are going to type the following keys