# How do I get Vim to recognize ESC key faster?

Tags: vim

I use Vim, almost exclusively in the console. When I exit insert mode by pressing `<ESC>`, there is a noticeable lag in Vim's recognizing the command. The lag is similar to the delay when I push the `<leader>` key, I assume to give me time to enter other characters in a mapping. Is there an option I can set to get Vim to recognize the escape key faster?

Comment: Are you running Vim in screen or tmux when this happens, by chance?

Comment: @echristopherson, Sometimes I'm in tmux and sometimes I'm not. It doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Do you have any maps or abbreviations which begin with ESC?

Comment: No, I don't have any maps that begin with `<ESC>`.

Comment: Are you sure that you or a rogue plugin hasn't done that? Double check with `:imap <Esc>`

Comment: I checked using `:imap <Esc>` and there are no mappings that begin with `<Esc>`.

Comment: Borrowing my answer from a similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849055/in-some-moments-vim-works-noticeably-slowly/4853136#4853136  I'm guessing you are having the same issue as this user.

Comment: You're right: that was the problem. iTerm has a bunch of keys mapped to send sequences beginning with `<Esc>` or `0x1B`. I deleted those mappings, restarted iTerm, and in Vim `<Esc>` responds noticeably faster. I also noticed that the problem was never present in MacVim, because it didn't have those terminal mappings.

Comment: @Lincoln Interesting. I wonder how Vim knows what iTerm has mapped.

Comment: @LincolnMullen: I'm having the same problem. Where in iTerm did you remove these mappings from? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 54):

If you are using tmux, that could be introducing a delay. Put this in your ~/.tmux.conf file:

```
set -s escape-time 0
```

Comment: Why could anybody think it may be useful to have such a delay by default?

Comment: I was having the same issue thinking that there was a problem with vim's configuration, but this solved the problem and now when I press the escape key, it works instantly!

Answer (score 6):

Blatently copying from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10856095/157237:

> You'll probably want to check `:help 'timeout'` and adjust settings
>   accordingly. You can set `timeoutlen` to a shorter duration if desired
>   (`ttimeoutlen` is by default set to `-1`, so it isn't used).

Comment: I tried setting `ttimeoutlen` (and `timeoutlen`) to a very small number. It does indeed change the length of time that Vim waits for other characters after `<esc>` or `<leader>`, but it doesn't change the delay between the time the final character is pressed and the time when Vim finishes exiting insert mode.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you have some slow action being performed when you leave insert mode.

You can check that by leaving insert mode with CTRL-C or using `:au InsertLeave`.

---

Edit:

You could also check if there are any mappings or abbreviations that are waiting to complete with `:iab` and `:imap`.

Comment: Using `<C-c>` does indeed get me out of insert mode without a lag. But `:au InsertLeave` does not list any auto commands.

Answer (score 1):

`set noesckeys`

help esckeys:

> ```
> 'esckeys' 'ek'      boolean (Vim default: on, Vi default: off)
>                     global
>                     {not in Vi}
>
>     Function keys that start with an <Esc> are recognized in Insert
>     mode.  When this option is off, the cursor and function keys cannot be
>     used in Insert mode if they start with an <Esc>.  The advantage of
>     this is that the single <Esc> is recognized immediately, instead of
>     after one second.  Instead of resetting this option, you might want to
>     try changing the values for 'timeoutlen' and 'ttimeoutlen'.  Note that
>     when 'esckeys' is off, you can still map anything, but the cursor keys
>     won't work by default.
>     NOTE: This option is set to the Vi default value when 'compatible' is
>     set and to the Vim default value when 'compatible' is reset.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This *might* be what is happening to you—it was what showed those symptoms for me.

After `map`ping the *Alt* key to be able to use *Meta* key combinations (in *Mate-Terminal* or *Konsole* on Debian), I noticed the same thing—getting out of insert mode took `timeoutlen`. That felt unacceptable, even with a short `timeoutlen`—but using `nmap` takes immediately :)

```
" Using `map` delays getting out of insert mode by timeoutlen!
for i in range(97,122)
    let c = nr2char(i)
    "exec "map \e".c." <M-".c.">"
    "exec "map! \e".c." <M-".c.">"
    exec "nmap \e".c." <M-".c.">"
endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a working answer on this page. I use vi keybindings in iTerm2 to quickly edit larger commands. Hitting the esc adds a delay before going into vi command-mode. You can turn the delay off by adding below property to your z-shell running config: ~/.zshrc

```
KEYTIMEOUT=1
```

Answer (score 0):

don't known if you still have this issue, but something that worked for me was
check if I had some map on **escape key**

with

```
:verbose imap <Esc>
```

once I noticed nothing was mapped, and using Control + C to go back to insert mode had no latency I just added a map to do so in my **init.vim**

```
imap <Esc> <C-c>
```

hope this works for all of you